# Java Sound Repeated Play

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to add sound to a game I've been working on, and I'm having trouble getting the sounds to play more than once. I think I've worked out the cause, but I'm not sure how to solve it. I'm using an enumerator I found while searching for a Java sound tutorial.

The problem is that I'm calling the sound within a thread, in my update() method, and that each time I call the play() method of the sound, it starts the clip over. The first time it's called, the sound plays fine (I may get a bit of a freeze), but all attempts afterwards to play the sound fail. I don't get any exceptions or errors, the sound just doesn't play.

```
public enum Sounds {
    RIFLE("rifle_fire.wav");

    private Clip clip;

    Sounds(String filename) {
        openClip(filename);
    }

    public synchronized void openClip(String filename) {
        try {
            URL audioFile = Sounds.class.getResource("/resources/sounds/" + filename);

            AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
            AudioFormat format = audio.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            clip.open(audio);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
            System.out.println(uae);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
            System.out.println(lue);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void play() {
        if(clip.isRunning()) clip.stop();
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();
    }

    public static void init() {
        values();
    }
}
```

That is the enumerator I use. It's called from the update() method of my main thread, which is updated every 20 ms. In the update method, I call it like this.

```
// If the left mouse button is held down, create a new projectile.
if(Globals.buttons[0] && !player.isOnCooldown()) {
    createParticle(pAngle);
    Sounds.RIFLE.play();
}
```

Someone suggested I need to close the line after using it, but the sound is only opened once... why would I need to close it? Anyone know what the problem is?